# Как установить язык программирования BASIC в FreeDOS?

Tags: dos, basic, freedos

Я установил FreeDOS и хотел бы установить оригинальную версию языка программирования BASIC в FreeDOS. Как мне это сделать? Что надо скачать и где?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _оригинальной_ версией?

Comment: Версия 1987 года :) Автор, а что вы планируете на нем написать?

Comment: Вот более современный аналог поиграться https://smallbasic-publicwebsite.azurewebsites.net

Comment: BASIC для DOS надо искать на каких-нибудь старых-престарых торрентах. У меня есть проект строкового интерпретатора BASIC (https://sourceforge.net/projects/obasic/), но и он сейчас уже под DOS не странслируется.

Comment: @NewView SmallBasic работает под виндой, а ТС хочет работать под DOS. :-)

Comment: Какой BASIC была широка используемим в MS-DOS? Тот я хочу установить и хотел бы узнать какой и как?

Answer (score 0):

В пакет FreeDOS 1.2 входят FreeBASIC и Bywater BASIC, ничего дополнительно устанавливать не нужно:

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/group-devel.html

FreeBASIC имеет режим совместимости с QuickBasic (который "тот самый оригинальный" для MS-DOS).